# How can I access documents a private Teams channel using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We have an application that reads files in a SharePoint documents folder, using Microsoft Graph. We have the site-selected permission enabled and the permissions have been assigned to the site. This has been working well for a few weeks now. The team that owns the data decided to move those files to a private Teams channel.

I know I can access a Teams channel through Microsoft Graph, but is there a way to access a private channel? Other than the owner making the channel public. Is there an application permission that I could add to the registration and assign to the site to make this accessable? I know I could probably do this with delegated permissions, but I really don't want to.

Comment: From my initial research, Currently, there are no application permissions that can be used to access private channels. You will need to use delegated permissions and have a user with appropriate permissions to access the private channel. I will update here if I find different results.

Comment: Thank you! I was kinda thinking that might be my only option. Thanks for confirming that.